# Load local UIImage asynchronously with caching

Tags: ios, xcode, caching, asynchronous, uiimage

UIScrollViewController

|-----UIImageView1, 2, 3, 4, 5...

I have a `UIScrollViewController` which has several subviews. Every subview contains a `UIImageview`, when scrolling the `UIImageView`, pages on either side of current page will be loaded using

```
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileName];
```

But when the local image file becomes really big (>2MB), the scrolling becomes very influent amd gets stuck.

Is there a way to avoid this? For example using a cache or doing it asynchronously?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can load images asynchronously, in another thread, or if you support only iOS higher than 4, it's quite easy to perform it with blocks.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, NULL), ^{
    UIImageView* imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileName]autorelease];       
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //Maybe correct the frame too
        [self.view addSubview:imageView];
    });
});
```

If you can't use blocks, you can execute in different thread, but it's a bit more involved.

Anyway, I recommend:

- Better have created UIImageViews added to the scrollview, with a 'dummy' or 'spinner', then when user interaction stops (detected via delegate method), you can reload the visible imageviews.
- When user is scrolling, better to load and cache UIImage objects for the images you want, (store them in an array or dictionary for example).
- Scale the UIImage content to fit the UIImageView frame inside ScrollView. That way during rendering time, UIImage will not 'autoscale' the provided image, so it will be faster.